# How to find equation of motion for this trajectory? - object leaves curved ramp at a given velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, velocity

Here is the sketch:

[image: Sketch for the problem]

The sketch is supposed to be side-view of the path of the object.

The following values are known:

- $r$ - radius of the circle that describes the path AB of the object
- $a$ - angle that characterizes the part of a circle that describes the path AB of the point
- $m$ - mass of the point
- $V_0$ - velocity

What I need to find out:

1. Equation of motion for AB
2. Equation of motion for BC
3. velocity at B
4. The distance DC

The dashed line is the object's trajectory after it leaves AB. $N$ is the normal force, $T$ is friction and $g$ is the gravitational acceleration.

I was able to solve this problem partially when AB is a straight line and $a$ represents the angle between AB and AD. So far I could come up with only this:

$m x'' = -T-mg \sin(?)$ <- in place of the question mark I would need the angle between AB and AD

$m y'' = N-mg \cos(?)$

$N = mg \cos(?)$

$T = \mu N = \mu mg \cos(?)$

$x'' = -g(\mu \cos(?) + \sin(?))$

$x' = -gt(\mu \cos(?) + \sin(?)) + c_1$

$x = g\frac{-t^2}{2}\left[ \mu \cos(?) + \sin(?)  \right] + c_1 t + c_2$

where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction. $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates with respect (both functions of time).

How do I deal with the fact the ramp is no longer a straight line but a curved line? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: More information required! Is this a graph? What happens at B? What is the dashed curve? How does the body even get to D?

Comment: I agree with Rob, something is off either in the description of what we are trying to solve for or in the plot itself. What I think you mean is the equation of motion for AB and then BC.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mixed up the letters. It is as you said. I corrected it.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of LaTeXifying your work, but I may have mis-interpreted your intent somewhere, so this should be checked. We have MathJax running on the site which means that math can be written in a $\LaTeX$-math-mode-alike language between single `$` for in-line equations and double `$$` for block set. I.e. `$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$` is typeset as $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.

Comment: I see. I'm gonna enclose math expressions in $ from now on. Thank you for editing btw

Comment: Does equation of motion mean a differential equation or the integrated algebraic solution for $s(t)$?

Comment: Also, for the second part of the problem the key will be to find the "flight time" of the projectile motion, then multiply this time by the horizontal component of the velocity as the particle leaves the ramp, which is a constant (neglecting air resistance).

Comment: Your equation of motion for the first part is also incorrect because it does not include the centripetal acceleration $v^2/r$.

Comment: nevermind, i don't need the solution anymore. i needed the solution to this problem otherwise i couldn't apply for the final exam, which was yesterday. so don't bother, i'm screwed anyway. next time i'll just pay someone off to solve it for me, i'm not gonna waste my time arguing with the mods

Comment: @Bryson S.: my attempt on the solution was for another type of problem where the ramp is a straight line, not a curved one and my only problem was that i couldn't figure out how to deal with the fact that it is curved ramp

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: From conservation of energy, you can find the velocity at the **release point**; after that it will follow a projectile motion. You can thus write equation of trajectory from the projectile motion.

Comment: I think you mean C.o.E. can be used to find the velocity at the *release* point, not the highest point. Based on the figure, the particle is experiencing projectile motion long before it reaches it's highest point $(\alpha>0)$.

Comment: @BrysonS. Yes...